# nth prime number in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, primes

I'm trying to find the nth prime number in xCode's Swift, but I can't seem to get this working, it just gives a list of prime numbers.

```
func nthPrimeNumber (n: Int) -> Int
{
    var prime: Int
    var divisor: Int
    var isPrime: Bool
    for (prime = 2;  prime <= 50;  ++prime )
    {
        isPrime = true;
        for (divisor = 2;  divisor < prime;  ++divisor )
        {
            if ((prime % divisor) == 0 )
            {
                isPrime = false
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == true )
        {
            println(" \(prime)")
        }
    }

    return prime
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any logic that terminates the loop once *n* primes are found.

Comment: I dont understand how to do that. I want, for instance, the 10th prime number, which would return a value of 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making minimal changes to your code, but, as commenter said, adding termination logic:

```
func nthPrimeNumber(n: Int) -> Int {
    var prime: Int
    var divisor: Int
    var isPrime: Bool
    var counter = 0
    for (prime = 2;  prime <= 50 && counter < n;  ++prime )
    {
        isPrime = true;
        for (divisor = 2;  divisor < prime;  ++divisor )
        {
            if ((prime % divisor) == 0 )
            {
                isPrime = false
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
        {
            counter++
        }
    }

    return prime-1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var isPrime: Bool {
        if self <  2 { return false }
        let squareRoot = Self(Double(self).squareRoot())
        if squareRoot * squareRoot == self { return false }
        for i in 2..<Self(Double(self).squareRoot().rounded(.up)) where self % i == 0 {
           return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

---

```
let twoDigitsPrimeNumbers = (1..<100).filter { $0.isPrime }
print(twoDigitsPrimeNumbers)  // [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

---

```
func nthPrime(nth: Int)-> Int {
    var primeCounter = 0
    var number = 2
    while true {
        if number.isPrime {
            primeCounter += 1
            if nth == primeCounter { return number }
        }
        number += 1
    }
}
nthPrime(1000)   // 7,919
```

Answer (score 0):

[Note: this code returns the `nth` prime, as required; not just 50 or 51, both non-primes.]

The `n` that you specified as an argument is totally ignored thus your computation terminated if and when `prime` became `51`.  All the primes under `50` were printed and a coincidental `51` is returned.  If you want the nth prime, you need to a) count up the primes as you encounter them and b) stop when you've got the nth.

You also have the issue to deal with of 'I want the 20th prime but I'm only looking for primes under 50' - there might not be a prime.

And, you are performing `prime % divisor` with `divisor < prime` but that divisor never needs to be more than `prime/2`.

All this together, with improvement in style leads to:

```
func nthPrimeNumber (var n: Int) -> Int
{
  if n < 1 { return 0 } // error condition

  var prime = 2

  while (true) { // find the `nth` no matter how large `prime`

    var isPrime = true
    for (var divisor = 2; divisor <= prime/2; ++divisor) {
      if 0 == prime % divisor { isPrime = false; break }
    }

    if isPrime {
      println (" \(prime)")
      if 0 == --n { return prime }
    }

    prime++
  }
}
```

and some results:

```
 39> nthPrimeNumber(1)
 2
$R7: (Int) = 2
 40> nthPrimeNumber(3)
 2
 3
 5
$R8: (Int) = 5
 41> nthPrimeNumber(10)
 2
 3
 5
 7
 11
 13
 17
 19
 23
 29
$R9: (Int) = 29
```

I encourage you to try `n` of `1000`!

Comment: 1 and 4 are not a prime numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
func isNumberDivisible(_ number: Int, by divisor: Int) -> Bool {
    number % divisor == 0
}

func isPrime(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
    
    var result: Bool = true
    
    for divisor in stride(from: 2, to: number, by: 1) {
        if isNumberDivisible(number, by: divisor) {
            result = false
        }
    }
    return result
}

for i in 0...100 { // you can choose whatever number you want
    if i == 0 || i == 1 {
        print("\(i) is not a prime number")
    } else if isPrime(i){
        print("\(i) is a prime number")
    } else {
        print("\(i) is not a prime numbe")
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer will have more value if you add a short description of why this approach is better or different than the other existing answers.

Comment: @Bek You’re right. As a beginner, it was a challenge for me to right my own solution. So I want to share it as a working answer with the community.