# Finding the n'th prime number | Variable 'prime' used before being initialized

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to write a Swift 3.0 method which returns the n'th prime number. There exists [other sources for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058291/nth-prime-number-in-swift) but these are all written before Swift 3.0 was released and therefore the code does not follow over. In my return statement `return prime` I am getting an error saying

> Variable 'prime' used before being initialized

Here is my source code:

```
func nthPrimeNumber(_ n: Int) -> Int {
var prime: Int
var modulo: Int
var checkPrime: Bool
var count = 0
for prime in stride(from: 2, to: 50, by: 1)
{
    if (count < n){
        checkPrime = true;
        for modulo in stride(from: 2, to: prime, by: 1)
        {
            if ((prime % modulo) == 0 )
            {
                checkPrime = false
            }
        }
        if (checkPrime)
        {
            count += 1
        }
    }
}

return prime
}
```

Comment: You should initialize it. `var prime: Int = 0` or `var prime: Int!`

Comment: @WeiJay I don't agree with your second suggestion because then if it doesn't have a value, your app will just crash, so it's not really a good fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BenjaminLowry's change will fix the compiler warning, but the algorithm will still be wrong. The problem here is the first `prime` used for the function and the second `prime` used in the for loop are independent variables, so the value used in the for loop won't affect your result, and thus your function will always return 0. Instead you need to do something like this:

```
func nthPrimeNumber(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    var result: Int = 0
    var checkPrime: Bool
    var count = 0
    for prime in stride(from: 2, to: 50, by: 1)
    {
        if (count < n){
            checkPrime = true;
            for modulo in stride(from: 2, to: prime, by: 1)
            {
                if ((prime % modulo) == 0 )
                {
                    checkPrime = false
                }
            }
            if (checkPrime)
            {
                count += 1
                result = prime
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

The same thing is true with your 2 uses of `modulo`. The outer `modulo` is unused and can be removed.

Comment: Beauty, this seems to be where I was getting my errors after fixing the uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

`prime` needs to have a value when initialized, e.g.

```
var prime: Int = 0
```

Otherwise the compiler will complain because theoretically if the code inside your if-statements doesn't run, then `prime` could not have a value and then be returned. Since your are returning an non-optional value `Int`, you have to make sure it will have a value no matter what.