# Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

Tags: swift

```
func isPrime(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
  var isPrimeNumber = true
    for divisor in 2...(x - 1) {
    if x % divisor != 0 {
    isPrimeNumber = true
  } else {
    isPrimeNumber = false
  }
 }
 return isPrimeNumber
}    

func printPrimes(upTo n: Int) {
  for y in 1...n {
     if isPrime(y) == true {
       print(y)
     }
    }
  }

printPrimes(upTo: 12)
```

Write a function called `printPrimes(upTo n: Int)`. The function should print the prime numbers that are between 1 and n. For example, if you pass in 100, the function should print the prime numbers between 1 and 100. A number is prime if it is only evenly divisible by itself and 1, and not evenly divisible by any other number. Call your function with several different values for n and verify that it prints the correct numbers.

I do not understand why I am getting this error message:

> > Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

Comment: When printing them there is no need to start from `1`. Just start from `2` and use the `Range` operator `..<` instead of `ClosedRange` operator `...`.  `for divisor in 2..<x {`and `for y in 2..<n {`. Btw `== true` is redundant `if isPrime(y) {` Btw 4 it is not a prime number. This logic will return true for `isPrime(4)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/28062081/2303865

Comment: You need to add an early exit to your for loop `break` in case it is false `func isPrime(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
    guard x > 1 else { return false }
    var isPrimeNumber = true
    for divisor in 2..<x {
        if x % divisor != 0 {
            isPrimeNumber = true
        } else {
            isPrimeNumber = false
            break
        }
    }
    return isPrimeNumber
}` or simply `return false` from inside your loop or `true` in the end if the loop completes without an early exit.

Comment: you can simplify it to `func isPrime(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
    guard x > 1 else { return false }
    for divisor in 2..<x {
        if x % divisor == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}` or even further adding a where clause to your loop `func isPrime(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
    guard x > 1 else { return false }
    for divisor in 2..<x where x % divisor == 0 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}`

Comment: The Sieve of Eratosthenes would be most appropriate for this kind of problem. It would avoid redundant calculations.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
for divisor in 2...(x - 1) {
```

for x = 2 or x = 1, upperbound will be less than lowerbound which in your case is 2.

You should put a check in this case that the value of x should always satisfy the condition that (x-1) will be greater than 2.